# Reading a file in C results in a crash

Tags: c, arrays, file, crash

iI'm trying to read a file and out the content into a struct array.

Here is how the data is formatted in the file:

> 1981,AARON,5

```
    size = getRawData(filein, records, currSize);
```

That line is where it get's called in main. filein is a file, records is a struct and currSize is an int

```
int getRawData(FILE *fp, struct NameRecord records[], int currSize){
printf("tick1inf\n");
printf("currSze = %d\n", currSize);
while (EOF != fscanf(fp, "%d,%[^,]%c,%[^,]%d", records[currSize].year,records[currSize].name, records[currSize].frequency)){
    currSize++;
    printf("currsize is %d\n", currSize);
}
printf("tick2infout\n");
return currSize;
```

}

The program crashes right when it gets to the while line to read in the data why is it crashing and what can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you're missing a few `&` on the variables you want to read data into.

Comment: number of elements in the scanf does not fit.

Comment: Joachim - thanks that helped me get to the counter to start ticking but the data doesnt get read into the struct still

Comment: Specifying a comma likely bad.

Comment: BLUEPIXY - really? wont it put the comma into the data?

Comment: Format of the data you are trying to load is not clear.

Comment: Also do this if you want to specify the partner comment. (eg @GabrielAppugliese)

Comment: try `fscanf(fp, "%d,%[^,],%d", &records[currSize].year,records[currSize].name, &records[currSize].frequency)`

Comment: that did not work, it doesnt actually store the data becuase i have it print out the year where the counter is but it just keeps reporting back 0 for every single line

Comment: You have 5 format specs and only 3 variables to stuff the values into.

Comment: Mark i put the %s but it doesnt seem to be reading in the data.

Comment: but doesnt the "%[^,]" just remove the comma so it doesnt interfere? because i was told that if i dont have that then scanf would read the comma right into the variable

Comment: It works well in the ***"try ..."*** where is i've tried here.

Comment: `struct NameRecord{
 int year;
 char name[32];
 int frequency;
};` Structure are you like?

Comment: Are you check the file open?

Comment: I was wrong to suggest replacing %c with %s, sorry. The %[^,] will read the 2nd comma-delimited field. The %c shouldn't be in your format string at all.  BLUEPIXY has the solution that's best.

Comment: yes thats actually exactly how the struct is then i have  struct NameRecord records[150000]; just before main i know its a big array size but thats just because the assignemt said to make it 150000